# An app on the play store promises to TRIM without root access but I highly doubt if it even works

Tags: root-access, file-system, lagging, maintenance

My phone is new so I can't root it because I don't wanna void my warranty just yet and trimming my phone would also not make a significant difference. Since most other apps on the Play Store promise to run TRIM only with root access, I don't think it's possible for this app to do so without root but if it can that's the best thing I can get. Can someone please confirm if this app actually works?

Link to the app:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lagfix.fstrimmer